# Confused about Typescript object types {} []

Tags: angular, typescript

I have never worked with lists, object lists etc in Typescript and im not sure how they work. The below code doesnt do much except create a few objects and create some temp values for them through a loop, but i want the console log to print out the second objects name ("image1") followed by the second objects height (21).

What is wrong with the below code? Since undefined is being printed out.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  image = {};
  images = [this.image];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      this.image = {name: "image"+i, height: 20+i};
      this.images[i] = this.image;
    }

    console.log(this.images[1][0]);
    console.log(this.images[1][1]);
  }

}
```

Comment: `this.images[1]` is `{name: "image1", height: 21}`. Are you expecting the `[0]` after that to work like `.name`? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong perse, but you can simply access your array's objects as you are by doing this:

```
console.log(this.images[1].name)
console.log(this.images[1].height)
```

You can use the names in there. If you're using TypeScript and an editor or IDE that supports TypeScript's language service; it'll even recommend values it knows are available!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  images:any[] = []

  ngOnInit() {
    this.images = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      let image = { name: "image" + i, height: 20 + i };
      this.images.push(image)
    }

    console.log(this.images);
    console.log(this.images[1].name);
    console.log(this.images[1].height);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access this.image[1] with an index [0] while the saved image is an object with `name` and `height` properties

You should access images by pointing the index of `this.images` then using property as a key instead of a second index

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   const image = {name: "image"+i, height: 20+i};
   this.images[i] = image;
 }

 console.log(this.images[0].name);
 console.log(this.images[1].name);
 console.log(this.images[2].height);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it in Javascript in a snippet :

```js
class HomeComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.image = {};
    this.images = [this.image];
    this.ngOnInit();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      this.image = {name: "image"+i, height: 20+i};
      this.images[i] = this.image;
    }

    console.log(this.images[1][0]);
    console.log(this.images[1][1]);
  }

}

let x = new HomeComponent();
```

Now let's break it up :

1 - you create an empty image : `image = {}`
2 - you create an array containing this image : `images = [{}]`
3 - you create a loop that iterates 3 times
4 - in it, you change the image and push it in the array

You then have an array of 3 elements (because you override the first value), with each having a name and height properties, that aren't the same.

You then try to display the key "0" & "1" of the second image of the array.

But it just has "name" and "height" !

If you want to print the keys of the second object, you can try this instead :

```js
class HomeComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.image = {};
    this.images = [this.image];
    this.ngOnInit();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      this.image = {name: "image"+i, height: 20+i};
      this.images[i] = this.image;
    }

    console.log(Object.entries(this.images[1]));
  }

}

let x = new HomeComponent();
```